# Angular2 @Input issue

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular2 and my trying my hand using @Input but I am not able to proceed because of the below issue. After the @Input the component does not proceed further. I have verified in chrome developer tools and I see that execution goes outside the class immediately after the @Input

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
    import {Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
    import 'rxjs/Rx';

    var availableJobs = [];


    @Component({
      selector: 'job-categories',
      templateUrl:'templates/job.categories.html',
      providers:[HTTP_PROVIDERS]

    })

    export class JobCategories{

      @Input('rows') rows: string;
      @Input('cols') columns: string;


constructor(http: Http){
        http.get('appjs/dummyjson.json').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(
            (data) => {
              availableJobs = data;
              console.log(availableJobs);
            });
        }
    }
```

Could someone please help me overcome.

The HTML tag is

Comment: What does "the component does not proceed further." and "execution goes outside the class" mean? I can't see anything being obviously wrong.

Comment: True. Hence, I came to StackOverflow for help. What it means is, F10 on chrome dev tools will not take the execution to next line but it takes me to the end of the class

Comment: What behavior do you expect?

Comment: I would want the HTTP call happen and see the data in the JSON. Any dummy data is fine for testing

Comment: The inputs and the Http call don't seem to be related. The Http call should be made before the inputs are processed. Input values are assigned when the `ngOnChanges()` lifecycle callback is called the first time (just before `ngOnInit()` is called. The constructor is executed before any lifecycle callback is called.

Comment: Could you please help me reorganise?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110100/discussion-between-raviteja-avvari-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Comment: Doesn't seem to be necessary. So, is the Http request sent to the server? Do you get an error in the browser console. What is the desired behavior?

Answer (score 2):

I would see a problem in your code. You forgot the `this` keyword within the `subscribe` callback:

```
constructor(http: Http){
    http.get('appjs/dummyjson.json').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(
        (data) => {
          this.availableJobs = data; // <-----
          console.log(this.availableJobs);
        });
    }
}
```

This way you will be able to see / use the `availableJobs` property in the template of the component...

Comment: Maybe OP didn't forget it, it's defined as local variable `var availableJobs = [];` not as instance property.

Comment: Yes but I guess that he wants to use `availableJobs` in the component template ;-)

Comment: @dfsq Yes, I did declare as a local variable. Thanks for the efforts. The issue is resolved

Comment: Great! What was the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the problem is in your html(template). and the dev tools will not brings you into the subscribe method(async call), for that please keep a debugger; inside subscribe.

Would like to see your Html.

should be used like

```
<job-categories [rows]="someRowVariable" [cols]="someColVariable" ></job-categories>
```

Answer (score 0):

this happened because of defining a **availableJobs** variable outside a class . Define it within class name **JobCategories**

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
    import {Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
    import 'rxjs/Rx';




    @Component({
      selector: 'job-categories',
      templateUrl:'templates/job.categories.html',
      providers:[HTTP_PROVIDERS]

    })

    export class JobCategories{
      var availableJobs = [];  //Define within a class
      @Input('rows') rows: string;
      @Input('cols') columns: string;


constructor(http: Http){
        http.get('appjs/dummyjson.json').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(
            (data) => {
              availableJobs = data;
              console.log(availableJobs);
            });
        }
    }
```